Diffeomorphism between half stadium
I am wondering if there is a diffeomorphism between half stadiums with different sizes. The Bunimovich stadium I consider is made of two parallel segments with two half circles tangent to the segments. So what is changing sizes are the segments.
Figure of the stadium:

I know that, from Riemann Mapping Theorem, one can find a diffeomorphism between the interior sets, but what can we say about the boundary?

You can find a diffeo between the two rectangular parts, which is the identity map on some upper stripe.
